# Не могу разобраться, как сделать верстку этой части со словами "Пиши!" "Вдохновляй!" и т.д

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы круг был на заднем плане, а слова на переднем? Как на рисунке. Подскажите пожалуйста.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Круг можно отобразить фоном используя `radial-gradient()`, и далее размещать текст любым удобным способом:

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 34px 88px;
  height: 420px; width: 538px;
  
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, #fbfddd 0 140px, #0000 142px), #fffeec;
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal 27px/1em sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 3.5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.text:nth-of-type(1) { color: #f38a7a; width: 100%; }
.text:nth-of-type(2) { color: #6cd6f1; }
.text:nth-of-type(3) { color: #efc394; }
.text:nth-of-type(4) { color: #db7151; width: 100%; font: bold 29px/1em sans-serif; letter-spacing: 2.7px; }
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="text">Напиши!</div>
  <div class="text">Прочти!</div>
  <div class="text">Вдохновись!</div>
  <div class="text">Вдохновляй!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

в css для круга напиши:

```
z-index: 1;
```

а для текста:

```
z-index: 99;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: почему для текста нужно ставить 99?

Comment: Не обязательно 99, это номер "слоя", написал 99 чтобы наверняка)